# Is it the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$``$Let M be a compact smooth manifold without boundary, and let $f$ be a smooth vector field on M. Consider the differential equation
$$\dot{x} = f(x).$$

The existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE guarantees that exists a unique smooth function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \times M \to M$ such that

**I.** $\phi(t,*):M \to M$ is a diffeomorphism for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$;

**II.** $\phi(t+s,x) = \phi(t,\phi(s,x))$ for all $t,s \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in M$;

**III.** for each $x \in M$,
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\phi(t,x) = f(x)."$$

I'm not sure if "*existence and uniqueness theorem*" is Picard-Lindelöf Theorem itself or a generalization.

Other question: is $\phi(*,x_0):\mathbb{R} \to M$ the solution of the differential equation for the inicial condition $x(0) = x_0$?

Comment: Yes. You solve the equation on local charts. Compactness plays an important role for the flow to be guaranteed to be defined for all real numbers (you could relax the hypothesis of compactness of the manifold to the vector field vanishing outside a compact set). 

You can find a nice proof/explanation in Milnor's Morse Theory book, including the "global" issue I mentioned above. However, property $I$ requires a more careful analysis other than the usual way Picard-Lindelof is stated.

Comment: Thanks! And about the second question: It is not clear to me who is "$x$". Is it any function of $\mathbb{R}$ into $M$? In this case a think that $\phi(*,x_0)$ really is the solution taking $x_0$ as inicial point.

Comment: Dear @AloizioMacedo, where can one read a careful analysis of property $\mathrm I$ as mentioned at the end of your comment?